# How to ignore random values from server using Python

Tags: python-3.x, client-server

I am working on client code where it gets connected to server. Server is performing some task and keeps on returning the data every 1 sec. This data is tuple `(7.6, 37)`, where `7.6` is the value of an area (which can be anywhere between 0 to 55) and `37` is the id of the data. This id is like counter which starts from 0 when server starts and keeps on incrementing until server is rebooted.

Client code has to see when the area value is less than `10.0` and perform further calculations. Sometimes in between server sends some noise values where area is less than `10.0` so we have to ignore that but if the value of area is less than `10.0` for more than 10sec, that means it's not noise and we can proceed with further calculations. So noisy values will always be present for 3-4secs but if it's more than 10secs, it's not noise.

To handle this I have made up some of the below logic.

```
runOnce = True

data = server.recv()  # Getting the values from server
area = data[0]
id = data[1]


if area < 10.0:
    if runOnce:
        checkId = id + 10
        runOnce = False
    else:
        if checkId > id:
            # This data is not noisy
```

So in the above code, I am taking a variable `runOnce` as True. Once I receive the area value, I am setting a `checkId` variable with `id+10` so if current id is 50, then I will check at 60. So at 60th id if area is still less than 10, that means, it has been 10 secs and thus the current data is not noisy. This seems to work fine but it it's actually the noise then this code doesn't report it.

How can I handle this logic?

Comment: thre is no loop ... this will not do things more then once. [mre]?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Its difficult to share code as its server dependent but I will try to simulate something